# HOW TO PAGINATE A DATA FROM API

Tags: json, laravel, api, pagination, bitbucket

I was able to fetch certain data before but when I tried to add more code for pagination. It doesnt work anymore. 
I need to paginate the data from API

error: **"Trying to get property 'name' of non-object."**

This is the result if I

if I dd($response) the results are:

```
    {#274 ▼
      +"pagelen": 10
      +"next": "https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/repositories/spycetek?page=2"
      +"values": array:10 [▶]
      +"page": 1
      +"size": 59
    }
```

// I should paginate this. Here is my code for the controller.

```
    public function index(Request $request, $page = 1)
    {

        $request = $this->client->get("https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/repositories/{$this->username}?page=" . $page,
            [
                'headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->token]
            ]);
        $response = json_decode($request->getBody()->getContents());
        $repositories = $response->values;

        $pagination = $response->pagelen;
        $has_next_page = $pagination['has_next_page'];
        $current_page = $pagination['page'];
        $has_previous_page = $pagination['previous'];
        $next_page = $pagination['next'];


        return view('bitbuckets.repository')->with(compact('repositories'),
            [ 'has_next_page' => $has_next_page,
                'current_page' => $current_page, 'has_previous_page' => $has_previous_page,
                'next_page' => $next_page]);
    }
```

```
**//this is my blade.php file**

    @extends('layoutss.layout')
    @section('content')
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="load" style="position: relative;">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" class="text-secondary">Repositories</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    @foreach($repositories as $key => $repository)

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{route('pull_request', ['name'=>$repository->name, 'state'=>'OPEN'])}}">{{$repository->name }}</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @if(isset($current_page))
                            <?php
                            $prev = $current_page - 1;
                            ?>
                            @if(($has_next_page == true) && ($has_previous_page == false))
                                <li><a href="{{url('/'.$next_page)}}">Next</a></li>
                            @elseif(($has_next_page == false) && ($has_previous_page == true))
                                <li><a href="{{url('/'.$prev)}}">Previous</a></li>
                            @elseif(($has_next_page == true) && ($has_previous_page == true))
                                <li><a href="{{url('/'.$prev)}}">Previous</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{url('/'.$next_page)}}">Next</a></li>
                            @endif
                        @endif
                       {{$repositories->links()}}
                    @endforeach

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
    @endsection
```

and this is my code for routes.

```
    Route::get('/{page?}', 'bb@index');
```

what is wrong with my codes
I messed up when it comes to pagination.
in blade.php was trying to display the list of all repositories and I wanted to paginate them. But I couldn't because of the error.

Comment: {{$repositories->links()}} it won't work because it not laravel pagination

Comment: Am I not using laravel pagination? How can I paginate it using laravel tho?

Comment: just remove this `{{$repositories->links()}}` , may be it will solve , and for laravel pagination you have to user laravel model and local database

Comment: I am actually not using database for this. is it possible to paginate without database?

Comment: yes as you are getting paginate data from  bit bucket you can use that